# limits and uses of C++20 template lambas

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, generic-lambda

A couple of related questions for C++ standard gurus.

The incoming C++20 [introduces](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/57b2c0f46b8f329314cc5e82f427694f6c05e7a5) template lambdas ([P0428R2](http://wg21.link/p0428r2)).

So instead of

```
auto x = [](auto x, auto y){ return x+y; };
```

we can specify the template parameter as follows

```
auto x = []<typename T>(T x, T y){ return x+y; };
```

So far, so good.

First question: can explicit template parameters, in template lambdas, only be deduced from arguments, or is it possible to add non-deduced template arguments?

Reading P0428r1 I don't see any explicit limitations but, also, I don't see examples of non-deduced template arguments.

In first approximation I suppose that non-deduced template arguments are legal because I see that the following silly code

```
int main()
 {   
   []<int = 0>(){ }();
 }
```

compiles and runs with both g++ (10.0.0 head) and clang++ (10.0.0 head).

Supposing that non-deduced template parameters are allowed, the second question is: how can I call a template lambda while providing a template parameter?

By example: given the following template lambda

```
auto x = []<std::size_t I>(auto t){ return std::get<I>(t); };
```

Is there some syntax for specifying the template parameter `I` when invoking such lambdas *without* explicitly naming `operator()`?

I've tried with

```
x<0u>(y);
```

but the `<` is interpreted as a relational operator.

I've tried simply adding `template`

```
x template <0u>(y);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: @RaymondChen - thanks but... no: doesn't answer. This question is strictly related to lambda.

Comment: Simple workaround: `[]<std::size_t I>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>, auto t) {} (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}, ...)`.

Comment: @Evg - intriguing workaround but solve the specific example, not the general question.

Comment: @max66: It does answer your question. Lambdas aren't some magical construct; they're just shorthand notation for what C++ can already do. The template parameters on a lambda are applied to the `operator()` of the lambda, just like the `auto` function parameters. Therefore, if you want to provide template arguments directly, you must use exactly the same syntax as you would for any other `operator()` where you want to provide template arguments.

Comment: @NicolBolas - well... lambda itself are syntactic sugar. I was oping there is other syntactic sugar to simplify this use.

Comment: @max66: Then edit your question to make it clear that you are looking for specialized syntax specifically for lambdas, rather than any syntax which would work. Of course, the answer would be "no", because again, a lambda is just a struct written for you by the compiler.

Comment: @NicolBolas - sorry but is extremely clear the the question is lambda specific. Clear in the title and clear in the body.

Comment: Was not clear that you were looking to see if C++20 added **new syntactic sugar** for invoking generic lambdas.

Comment: @RaymondChen - not only: there is also the first question: it's legal a non-deduced template parameter? Reading the standard I don't understand this.

Comment: @max66: "*Reading the standard I don't understand this.*" Um... why not? I don't see how you could have read the lambda-template-header section of the standard and see a prohibition on it.

Comment: The documented you cited gives the revised syntax as permitting a `<`*template-parameter-list*`>`, and there are no stated restrictions on what can go into that template parameter list. Not sure what's not to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no special restrictions on template headers in lambda functions. Lambdas are after all just shorthand for what you could do already with any `operator()` overload.

There is no special syntax for providing template arguments when invoking the `operator()` of a lambda function. If you have template parameters which are not deduced, you will have to use the traditional mechanisms for providing those template arguments. IE: `lamb.operator()<Args>(...)`.

Comment: Do you mean something like `x.operator()<0>()`?

Comment: @L.F.: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Non-deduced lambda template arguments are legal. The syntax for calling them is similar to the existing function notation required when a method calls an overloaded operator of the same class; and especially if it is an overloaded operator template.

I show the most verbose combination in the example below, where the `template` keyword is also required as the lambda has a dependent name:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
void test()
{
  std::tuple tup{42, "eggs"};
  auto x = []<std::size_t I>(auto t){ return std::get<I>(t); };
  int i = x.template operator()<0>(tup);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  test<float>();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: True. However, (current release of) Clang might not like (e.g ICE) it in some cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986436/c-quickfix-to-clang-frontend-ice-when-explicitly-specifying-template-parameter