# C++ quickfix to Clang frontend ICE when explicitly specifying template parameter to operator()?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, clang++

#### What quick-fix can we use while `<lambda>::operator<T>()` explicit call is not fix yet ?

- Reported issue on LLVM bug report : https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49881

Considering the following minimal reproduction case example :

```cpp
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    // KO, explicit template parameter

    const auto lambda_1 = []<typename T>(){};

    [&lambda_1]<typename ... Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...>){
        ((lambda_1.template operator()<Ts>()), ...);
    }(std::tuple<int>{});

    // OK, template deduced using parameter

    const auto lambda_2 = []<typename T>(T){};

    [&lambda_2]<typename ... Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...>){
        ((lambda_2(Ts{})), ...);
    }(std::tuple<int>{});
}
```

The issue here is, that such solution requires `Ts...` to be default constructible.

Thus, it does not work with types which are not, such as lambdas with storage,
for instance :

```cpp
// KO, Ts... is not default constructible

const auto lambda = []<typename T>(T){};

    int i{0};
    [&lambda]<typename ... Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...>){
        ((lambda(Ts{})), ...);
    }(std::tuple{
        [i]() {}
    });
```

#### **Question** :

- Are we condemned to temporarily disable Clang support to our projects, and wait for a patch,
  or is there any quick-fix we can use to make this work until the next release(s) *(that will fix this ICE)* ?

Comment: It depends what part you want to keep, you might replace your lambda by an old-way functor class.

Answer (score 1):

A "tag" struct might help to pass type and allow deduction:

```
template <typename T>
struct Tag
{
    using type = T;
};
// or
// template <typename T> using Tag = std::type_identity<T>;
```

then instead of:

```
const auto lambda_1 = []<typename T>(){/*...*/};
lambda_1.template operator()<SomeT>();
```

You might have:

```
const auto lambda_2 = []<typename T>(Tag<T>){ /*...*/};
lambda_2(Tag<SomeT>{});

// C++14: No constraints on tag
const auto lambda_3 = [](auto tag){ using T = typename decltype(tag)::type; /*...*/ };
lambda_3(Tag<SomeT>{});
```

Comment: You're right. That's A.Alexandrescu `Type2Type` design btw, back to "modern C++ design" old time.