# Shortest way to call templated lambda in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, method-call

Imagine following toy example of templated lambda:

```
auto f = []<typename T>(){};
```

The shortest way I know to call this lambda for `int` type is `f.operator()<int>();`.

[Try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/Pr9jM5rY6)

Does anybody know if there is simpler/shorter syntax for calling templated lambda?

Of cause `f<int>();` doesn't compile, but would be nice to have such syntax similar to template function call.

But maybe in C++ standard they invented for lambda some special shortcut alias that I don't know about, like `f._<int>();`, here imaginary `_` is a name of method that just perfect-forwards all args to `.operator()` method. Is there anything like that? Or maybe `f.call<int>()`?

I understand that lambda behaves like simple functor class with method `.operator()`, hence same long call syntax as for templated functor `f.operator()<int>()`. But in your custom functor you can invent alias method `_` that forwards args, is there such similar alias in lambda?

As @RedFog told it is possible to implement a helper function that you use like `call<int>(f);` but I don't know how to implement such function for very general case - imagine if lambda has a mix of `typename` and `auto` params, like `[]<typename A, auto B, typename Q>{};`, I don't know how to write very generic helper function for such mixed case.

Comment: what about `call<int>(f)` or `call<int>(f)()`?

Comment: @RedFog You mean to create external helper function? As a backup solution could be, thanks! But I'm curious if standard lambda may have some ready-made `_()` method for doing such shortcuts. Need some experts to tell us for sure if such extra method exists or not.

Comment: @RedFog Also helper function can't probably cover all template params types. Imagine if lambda has long list of combinations of `auto` and `typename` params like `[]<typename T, auto X, typename Q>{};` then I don't know how to implement a helper `call()` function for supporting any list of template params.

Comment: yes, it can not solve all the problem, just for the usual case of `typename...`. but to *if standard lambda may have some ready-made `_()` method for doing such shortcuts*, I'm afraid not.

Comment: Given that there isn’t any special syntax, [limits and uses of C++20 template lambas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592122/limits-and-uses-of-c20-template-lambas) seems like a duplicate.