# Why does C++20 not allow to call a generic lambda with an explicit type?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20

```
auto f1 = []<typename T>(T) { return T{}; };
auto f2 = []<typename T>()  { return T{}; };

int main()
{
    f1(1);     // ok
    f2<int>(); // err: expected primary-expression before 'int'
}
```

Why does C++20 not allow to call a generic lambda with an explicit type?

Comment: Do you really mean **why** (which the accepted answer doesn’t address), or does this answer your question? [limits and uses of C++20 template lambas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592122/limits-and-uses-of-c20-template-lambas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax to invoke overloaded template operator () function supplying template parameters is

```
auto f1 = []<typename T>(T) { return T{}; };
auto f2 = []<typename T>()  { return T{}; };

int main()
{
    f1(1);     // ok
    f2.operator ()<int>(); // Ok
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YzY7njPGh

Comment: Just a nitpick, but in this case the `operator()` is not overloaded. It's just a template. Solution remains the same.

Comment: @super It is an overloaded operator, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Not sure what part of that link is relevant here. The unnamed struct generated by the lambda syntax will only have one `operator()`, so it's not overloaded. What am I missing?

Comment: @super It is called an overloaded operator in contrast to built-in operators, not in the sense of overloaded function.